# Partion a table based on date created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I hope someone can help me.

I have a very large table (10Millon) to purge the data from. The business requirement is:

1. Keep data that is <= 14 days in the main table
2. Purge data that is > 14 days into a flat file

The table has `Created_date`.

How can I partition the table based on the above requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly do this because the partition function values must be constants. They cannot be computed because if that computation changed its result the data on disk would become invalid.

You can partition by day. This will help you query for data older than 14 days and you can drop old partitions after exporting them.